# Como hacer un div punteagudo como una burbuja de chat

Tags: html, css

tengo la siguiente duda de como hacer un div punteagudo **NOTA**: me refiero a solo uno no con dos div por que asi lo se hacer aqui les dejo una imagen de lo que quiero y un poco de codigo

**esto es lo que quiero lograr**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
esto es lo que tengo

```css
#triangle{

 width: 250px;
  height:250px;
  background-image:url(avatar.png);
background:black;
}
.triangulo {
position:absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-right: 60px solid transparent;
  border-left: 60px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;
  border-top: 60px solid black;
margin-top:250px;
margin-left:65px;
}
```

```html
<div id="triangle">

 <div class="triangulo"></div>
</div>
```

como veran lo que me gustaria es hacerlo con un solo div y asi poner una imgen de fondo el el div para que quede como en la foto , alguna idea o tips para lograr esto?

Comment: Hola, ando de pasada pero en caso de que no te den la respuesta que necesitas quizás esto te encamine o te ayude a sacar ideas.
https://leaverou.github.io/bubbly/

Saludos.

Comment: gracias @JulioLago lago  le dare una checada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola te voy a dar dos ideas de como hacerlo:

1. Usa `before` y `after` para crear dos elementos abajo con esa forma.
2. Usa la propiedad CSS `clip-path`

**Opción 1:**

Recomendaciones con esta opción:

- El color de los pseudo elementos deben ser el mismo del siguiente elemento.
- Si sabes usar variables puedes usar la misma variable para los pseudo elementos y el color de fondo del próximo elemento.

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}

div{
  font-size: 2em;
  background-color: dimgray;
  background-image: url('http://picsum.photos/800/600/?=random');
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 80vh;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 50vh; /*ignora esta linea, es para centrar el texto, pero no es lo mejor*/
  position: relative;
}

div::before,
div::after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 2em;
  width: calc(50% + 2em);
  background: lightcyan; /*El mismo color de fondo que el siguiente elemento*/
}

div::before{
  left: -2em;
  transform: skew(45deg);
}

div::after{
  right: -2em;
  transform: skew(-45deg);
}

article{
  background: lightcyan;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  texto de prueba
</div>
<article>
  otro elemento
</article>
```

**Opción 2**

Recomendaciones con esta opción:

- La otra opción es un poco más avanzada ya que la propiedad clip path debe combinarse con la función calc y variables css.
- Además de usar margin para que el siguiente elemento no se pegue al anterior.
- Es una opción complicada, pero permite usar los seudoelementos del contenedor en otras cosas, como por ejemplo la flecha que tiene la imagen del ejemplo, entre otras cosas.
- Otro beneficio, es que el triángulo y su tamaño se modifica a la perfección con una medida que declares en el body (o en el contenedor padre del fondo con el triángulo), de esa manera aunque la configuración es tediosa, las modificaciones posteriores son más rápidas, ya que cuando quieras cambiar el tamaño de esta, solo lo tienes que hacer en un solo lugar y no en varios.

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}

body{
  --h: 4rem;
}

div{
  font-size: 2em;
  background-color: dimgray;
  background-image: url('http://picsum.photos/800/600/?=random');
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 80vh;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 50vh; /*ignora esta linea, es para centrar el texto, pero no es lo mejor*/
  position: relative;
  clip-path: 
    polygon(     
      0% 0%, 
      0% calc(100% - var(--h)),     
      calc(50% - var(--h)) calc(100% - var(--h)),     
      50% 100%,     
      calc(50% + var(--h)) calc(100% - var(--h)),     
      100% calc(100% - var(--h)),     
      100% 0%);
  margin-bottom: calc( var(--h) * -1 )
}

article{
  background: lightcyan;
  --y: 1em;
  padding: var(--y);
  padding-top: calc(var(--h) + var(--y));
}

/*Lo siguiente es para crear la flecha del banner*/

div::before{
  content: '';
  width: calc(var(--h) / 1.5) ;
  height: calc(var(--h) / 1.5);
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: calc(var(--h) / 1.5);
  transform: 
    translateX(-50%)
    rotateZ(45deg);
  box-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0 0 white;
}
```

```html
<div>
  texto de prueba
</div>
<article>
  otro elemento
</article>
```

Comment: genial gracias por tu aporte amigo!

Comment: Me alegro que te haya servido. Éxitos!